# Postgres records not selected in order by multiple application threads

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing, sequential

We have a process where we need to process records in order, not in which records were received, but in the order of a timestamp column (**recdate**) that we receive from the source system, and for a specific **otherid**.

For example: We receive 3 messages for the **otherid** value 1 and we receive 5 messages for the **otherid** value 2.
We have a 15 seconds grace period where we wait for all the messages pertaining to one **otherid** value "to settle", before messages are eligible to be selected for processing. So there can be multiple messages accumulated for a particular **otherid** in those 15 seconds, but all with a different **recdate** timestamp. We "cook" them for 15 seconds since they come out of order (but never by more than 1-2 seconds), so to make sure they are all there before we start selecting by oldest message for a particular **otherid**.

First call to the function to select a message to process, should select the oldest message regardless of **otherid** value. Let's say the oldest message for **otherid** 1 was selected. We then store **otherid** value 1 into the **locktbl** table, so no other message for that **otherid** is selected until we process the message we selected, and unlock that **otherid** by deleting its value from the lock table afterwards. We also change the status of the selected message to 'InProcess', since only messages with status 'New' are considered. This may seem redundant, since **otherid** for the message is already locked, but we decided to do it to speed up search for the next 'New' message in the table.
In the mean time, oldest message for **otherid** 2 or for any other **otherid** can be selected by any other thread, and once selected, **otherid** is also locked, and so on.

Since this is all multithreaded, messages arrive out of order.
Also, there are sometimes hundreds of threads calling the function to select the next message to process at the same time.

The process works most of the time, but there are some types of messages that arrive really close to each other and for the same **otherid**, and in those cases, we sometimes have messages selected to be processed out of order for the same **otherid**. A newer message is selected, and locks the **otherid** prior to older message being selected to be processed, and then of course older message waits, and is processed after.

```
create table tbl1 (
    recid bigint not null
    ,otherid bigint not null
    ,statuscode character varying(16) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DEFAULT 'New'::character varying
    ,recdate timestamp(6) with time zone not null
    ,msgbody text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL
)

create table locktbl (
    otherid bigint not null, 
    lockdate timestamp(6) with time zone not null
)

insert into tbl1 (recid,otherid,statuscode,recdate,msgbody)
values
(1,1,'New','2023-05-04 13:16:42.004111+00','body1')
,(2,1,'New','2023-05-04 13:16:42.00521+00','body2')

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_getnextmessage(
    )
    RETURNS TABLE(ret_recid bigint, ret_otherid bigint, ret_msgbody text) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL SAFE 
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
declare
    _recid bigint := null;
    _otherid bigint := null;
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    INTO _recid, _otherid
        t1.recid, t1.otherid
    FROM tbl1 t1
    WHERE t1.recdate < (now() - interval '15 second')
    AND t1.statuscode = 'New'
    AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from locktbl l where l.otherid = t1.otherid)
    ORDER BY t1.recdate
    -- FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
    LIMIT 1;

    IF _recid > 0 THEN 
        INSERT INTO locktbl (otherid, lockdate)
        VALUES (_otherid, now());

        UPDATE tbl1 t1
        SET statuscode = 'InProcess'
        WHERE t1.recid = _recid;            

        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT 
            t1.recid
            ,t1.otherid
            ,t1.msgbody
        FROM tbl1 as t1
        WHERE t1.recid = _recid;
    ELSE
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT 
            t1.recid
            ,t1.otherid
            ,t1.msgbody
        FROM tbl1 as t1
        LIMIT 0;    
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Table **locktbl** has a unique constraint on the **otherid** column.
We tried with **FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED**, or without it, but still getting records selected out of order with respect to **recdate**. We are not concerned if we get blocking errors or unique key violation errors, we can handle those in the app code. We just need them not to be selected out of order.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: The SO community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and the actual results you received, all as text - **no images**; also adding a  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful. Specifically what is the data type of the column `recdate`? Offhand, and without further information, I would guess *varchar* or *text*.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry, and assumed "everyone knows what I know" and then also something I don't. How's this?

Comment: "Everyone knows what I know", bad assumption. Better off assuming *they know nothing*. But see my answer below.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be jumping through a lot of hoops to select the next item from a queue. With a slight schema modification you can do this in 1 statement. And that statement can be wrapped in function if desired (but not required).  
First off get rid of the `locktbl` table and move the column `lockdate` to `tbl1`. You can either let it default to null but if you want to avoid `Null` values then set the default to `-infinity`. See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/kIUG1JtH).

```
create or replace
function fn_getnextmessage()
    returns table( ret_recid   bigint
                 , ret_otherid bigint
                 , ret_msgbody text
                 ) 
    language sql
    volatile 
    parallel unsafe
as $$
    update tbl1 
       set lockdate = now()
         , statuscode = 'InProgress'
     where recid = 
           (select recid
              from tbl1 t1  
             where t1.recdate < (now() - interval '15 second')
               and t1.statuscode = 'New'
               and lockdate = '-infinity'::timestamp(6) with time zone
             order by t1.recdate
             limit 1
           ) 
    returning recid, otherid, msgbody    
$$;
```

I have assumed the column `tbl1.recid` is unique, if not you should create a unique or PK and use that in the above query.  
Note: I marked the function as **parallel unsafe** instead of parallel safe. See the [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-safety.html)

> Functions and aggregates must be marked PARALLEL UNSAFE if they write
> to the database, access sequences, change the transaction state ...